# Retrieving Google Search Analytics by "google-api-php-client" library

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client, google-search-console

I'm still a beginner in any API, so need help.
As I understand, service *"Webmasters"* in [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/) library allows me to receive data like `CTR`, `Clicks`, etc.

I downloaded lib files from github and puted it into localhost. Then in *Google Developers Console* I created project (dont't really understand, for what? This project doesn't contain any info about site, which search info I need). And after that created server key for project (by *"Add credentials"* in *Google Developers Console*, without typing any ip for it). Google Search Console API is enable. I'm full user for my site (I can see it in *Google Search Console*). Also I have Google account, sure, and logged in.

My source file created in [examples](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples) folder of lib, among other examples:

```
include_once "templates/base.php";    
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/Google/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$apiKey = "AIzaSyCOJ56353XByxh8rCpfgfhgfhZzopSLUe"; // Value of server key, that I created in for my project ().

if (strpos($apiKey, "<") !== false) {
  echo missingApiKeyWarning();
  exit;
}
$client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);

//here are my efforts
$service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
var_dump($service->searchanalytics->query(
'http://sschesnok.com.ua',
 new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest())); //I'm not sure about correctness of 2nd param
```

I see error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites?key=AIzaSyCOJXByxh8rCpfZzopSLUerl6LjWmziqhw: (401) Login Required' in    G:\server\www\gwt\gs\src\Google\Http\REST.php:110
Stack trace:
#0 G:\server\www\gwt\gs\src\Google\Http\REST.php(62):   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request), Object(Google_Client))
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 G:\server\www\gwt\gs\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 G:\server\www\gwt\gs\src\Google\Http\REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner-&gt;run()
#4 G:\server\www\gwt\gs\src\Google\Client.php(593): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#5 G:\server\www\gwt\gs\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(237): Google_Client-&gt;execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#6 G:\server\www\gwt\gs\src\Google\Service\Webmasters.php(492): Google_Service_Resource-&gt;call('list', A in <b>G:\server\www\gwt\gs\src\Google\Http\REST.php</b> on line <b>110</b><br />
```

`(401) Login Required` - where am I wrong? What login and where need I to pass?

And 2nd question - what need I to pass as second param to `query` method?

Please, help me to figure it out: to retrieve search info vie this lib. I have never worked with any API, so understand almost nothing in it.

Comment: api key is used for public apis you are trying to get private data use Oauth2.  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php

Comment: @DalmTo, do u mean, that I have to use client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri instead of API key? And will it be better to do it using an example according to your link, if I want to retrieve search data?

Comment: Yes you need to use client id and client secret which is Oauth2 instead of api key which is not Oauth2.  I don't have an example of Oauth2 with search data you can read that tutorial and edit it once you understand how it works.

Comment: Can u help me with understanding? U said, that API key || OAuth 2.0 is used. But [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication), in 1st table I saw, that in some cases key && OAuth 2 are used. What are these cases? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is my working code. I used [dev-master](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) version of this lib.

```
include_once "templates/base.php";
session_start();

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/Google/autoload.php');

$client_id = '**********************.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = '*******************';
$redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/gwt/gr/examples/user-example.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters");

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    $q = new \Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();

    $q->setStartDate('2015-09-01');
    $q->setEndDate('2015-09-01');
    $q->setDimensions(['page']);
    $q->setSearchType('web');
    try {
       $service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
       $u = $service->searchanalytics->query('http://sschesnok.com.ua', $q);
       echo '<table border=1>';
       echo '<tr>
          <th>#</th><th>Clicks</th><th>CTR</th><th>Imp</th><th>Page</th><th>Avg. pos</th>';
          for ($i = 0; $i < count($u->rows); $i++) {
            echo "<tr><td>$i</td>";
            echo "<td>{$u->rows[$i]->clicks}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$u->rows[$i]->ctr}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$u->rows[$i]->impressions}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$u->rows[$i]->keys[0]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$u->rows[$i]->position}</td>";

            /* foreach ($u->rows[$i] as $k => $value) {
                //this loop does not work (?)
            } */
            echo "</tr>";
          }             
        echo '</table>';
     } catch(\Exception $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }  
}

<div class="request">
<?php 
    if (isset($authUrl)) {
      echo "<a class='login' href='" . $authUrl . "'>Connect Me!</a>";
    } else {
      echo <<<END
     <form id="url" method="GET" action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}">
       <input name="url" class="url" type="text">
       <input type="submit" value="Shorten">
     </form>
     <a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>
END;
}
?>
</div>
```

Access token expires perodically.

Comment: Please, how did you find all the documentation in order to work with that google client? I can't find anything. In Google - they only show how to use the Books service, but where is the documentation for webmaters service?

Comment: @Upsilon42 Maybe, this will be helpful for you: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/quickstart/quickstart-java

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer Boollean! But ive already visited these links. I downloaded the php client and in their example it's only for the Books service, i need search console service. And the other link os for java, im using php. How did you know how to use Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest for example, and all that program you did?

Comment: @Upsilon42 I don't remember how exactly, but remember, that it was difficult. But today I've found [docs with examples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php?hl=en) . I didn't try it, but looks not as scary as 2 years ago.

Comment: We tried this code .. We receive the following error

Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.in/searchAnalytics/query: (403) User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://www.mysite.in/'. 

See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.